# How X11/Qt/Gtk/ implements scrolling

Tags: scroll

I hope someone can help me with this: how X11/Qt/Gtk implements scrolling? I do
not want to know how to use their APIs to use scroll on a program, but how the APIs
implements scrolling.

For instance, the program receives a request to redraw itself because the user had
scrolled only a single line down/up. Do the program redraw only this single line?

Does it uses blit operations? 3D and/or 2D acceleration? Most important: where can I find
references about this subject?

This question could also be: how to implement scrolling in your homemade windowing system.

If someone needs to know:
 - custom operating system made from scratch with assembly/C
 - video using VGA